# Is there a method to add to a list (of list(of String)) byVal?

Tags: vb.net, pass-by-value

I'd like to repeatedly add lists of strings to a bigger list collection, but it seems that the list.add function is adding the items `byref`. How can I change the below example code to pass the elements `byval` so that they're not cleared when I re-use variables:

```
    Dim inner As New List(Of String)
    Dim outer As New List(Of List(Of String))
    Dim eleCount As Integer = 0
lbltop:
    inner.Add("a")
    inner.Add("b")
    inner.Add("c")

    outer.Add(inner)
    Debug.Write(outer(0)(0).ToString())
    inner.Clear()

    Debug.Write(outer(0)(0).ToString())

    eleCount += 1
    If eleCount < 2 Then
        GoTo lbltop
    End If
```

this writes `a` then there's an out of range exception for the next `debug.write` statement.

I'd like it to write `aa` then loop to add another inner element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<T>` is a reference type. Only way to not effect it when calling `Clear()` is to add a clone of it to outer instead. You can do so by using `.ToList()`

```
outer.Add(inner.ToList())
```

But I actually think the most clear way is to instead assign inner a new List instead of calling Clear, than you dont have to do above.

```
inner = new List(Of String)
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a list of reference types somewhere that I'm missing? I seem to bump into this issue a lot!

Comment: All structs are value types and all others reference types.

Comment: `Structure`s are value types, `Class`es are reference types, any numerical base type like `Byte`, `Short`, `Integer` and so on are value types, `Date` is a value type, `String` is a reference type that behaves in some points as a value type. In short, anything that can be `Nothing` is a reference type, anything else is a value type.

Comment: @Nostromo except `Nullable<T>` which is a value type that can be nothing. ;-) (or seem to be nothing)

Comment: As far as the Microsoft documentation goes, `Nullable<T>` is a `Structure`, so it can't be `Nothing`.

Comment: @Nostromo Well, `Dim a As Integer? = Nothing` is valid code. But there is some special handling of nullable types to make them seem to be nothing.

Comment: Alternatively, you could add `New List(Of String)(inner)` which would (in my opinion) make your intention a little clearer.

Comment: @Magnus You can do `Dim a As Integer = Nothing` as well, but that only means to set `a` to it's data type's default value